# Why "None Type" is returned while Selection Sort implementation in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, nonetype, selection-sort

> I'm trying to implement Selection Sort Algorithm in Python and for
> some reason Sorted Array is returned as `None` . Here's the Code:

```
#Selection Sort
def selection_sort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i+1,len(array)):
            if array[j]<array[min_idx]:
                min_idx = j
                
        array[i],array[min_idx] = array[min_idx],array[i]
    

array = [1,7,5,3,9]
print(f"Original Array: {array}")

x=selection_sort(array)
print(f"Sorted Array: {x}")
```

> Output:

```
Original Array: [1, 7, 5, 3, 9]
Sorted Array: None
```

Comment: I don't see any `return` in your code.

Comment: `return array` at the end of method. Python returns a `None` by default, if you don't have one.

Comment: Your function changes the state of the list in-place, so try `print(f"Sorted Array: {array}")` to print the new state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is wat u can do:

1. U have passed a list of values which is passed as reference to the function.
   so u can get expect the result i.e. the sorted array in the list u passed --> array. so
   u can do something like this

   ```
   print(f"Sorted Array: {array}")
   ```
2. if u want to keep the original list intact , pass a copy to the function like below:

   ```
   x=selection_sort(array[:])
   ```

   and return value from your function by adding the the line at the end as below:

   ```
   return array
   ```

   and print as u did in your code

Comment: You can also use the `copy()` method of lists like this: `x=selection_sort(array.copy())`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you forgot to add return, and therefore the function returns None.
This code works for me:

```py
#Selection Sort
def selection_sort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i+1,len(array)):
            if array[j]<array[min_idx]:
                min_idx = j
                
        array[i],array[min_idx] = array[min_idx],array[i]
    return array
    

array = [1,7,5,3,9]
print(f"Original Array: {array}")

x=selection_sort(array)
print(f"Sorted Array: {x}")
```